# Spring boot: Check if Resource has Annotation in Filter Level

Tags: java, filter

As we can get resource method using ResourceInfo in Java EE

```
Method method = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod();
Class<?> clazz = resourceInfo.getResourceClass();
return (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(AnyClass.class) || method.isAnnotationPresent(AnyClass.class));
```

Using above code we can check if given resource have AnyClass as annotation. We can check this in the ContainerRequestFilter level in JavaEE

I am unable to find the proper way to find the annotation in spring boot filter level